# how to know which source file or group I right click in the Xcode's project navigator?

Tags: xcode, plugins

I am writing a xcode plugin,and I am getting into a trouble.

I created a menuitem name "Show In xcBuddy" when right click the source file in the Xcode's project navigator，for example:

[right click menu with "Show In xcBuddy"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTZWo.png)

but I don't know which source file or group .
I try to explor the notification when right click,but there is nothing to do with it.
print notification.name and [notification.object class]:

```
2016-02-15 14:15:44.960 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.960 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.966 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.966 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.967 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.967 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.967 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.967 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.967 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.967 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.967 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.968 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.968 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.968 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.968 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.968 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.968 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.969 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.969 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.969 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.969 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.969 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.969 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.969 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.969 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.969 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.970 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.970 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:44.970 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.051 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.054 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.055 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.056 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.057 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.057 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.058 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.058 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.058 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidAddItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.067 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidChangeItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.067 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidChangeItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.068 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidChangeItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:45.068 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidChangeItemNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:15:55.052 Xcode[17890:649266] NSThreadWillExitNotification, NSThread
2016-02-15 14:15:55.097 Xcode[17890:649258] NSThreadWillExitNotification, NSThread
2016-02-15 14:16:00.701 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidEndTrackingNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:16:00.701 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidEndTrackingNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:16:00.703 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidCompleteInteractionNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:16:00.703 Xcode[17890:649133] NSMenuDidCompleteInteractionNotification, NSMenu
2016-02-15 14:16:00.712 Xcode[17890:649133] NSApplicationWillUpdateNotification, IDEApplication
2016-02-15 14:16:00.712 Xcode[17890:649133] NSWindowDidUpdateNotification, IDEWorkspaceWindow
```

Comment: you maybe able to cherry pick some logic form here http://sam.dods.co/blog/2015/05/02/stencil-xcode-plugin/